# Gulp - JADE - browserSync not reload automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

I use gulp for create. I use browser sync for see the preview of my pages. But I can't configure gulp to reload automatically. When I make a change in the browser, I have to reload manually only with jade files. I use and compile CSS to SCSS and this if change automatically...

Which one is my error, why gulp not reload my jade or html files in the preview?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minimifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

// JADE
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src('./jade/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});

// SASS
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('./sass/styles.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: true
    }))
    .pipe(minimifyCss({
        keepBreaks: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// browserSync
gulp.task('default', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./"
    });

    gulp.watch("./sass/styles.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("./jade/*.jade", ['jade']);
    gulp.watch("./*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not including your jade or sass function in your parameters

> gulp.task('default', ['sass'], ['jade'], function(){
>
> > gulp.watch("./sass/styles.scss", ['sass']);
> >
> > gulp.watch("./jade/*.jade", ['jade']);
>
> })

gulp default

Comment: Where I have to write this code.... In the last task, in the comment // browserSync because it's very similar
or I must create other task

Comment: just add the parameters into the browser sync function [More info](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/)

Comment: I create a new project and now it works... Add the paremeters ['sass', 'jade'] too... Thanks